# how to run a external js script function from console

Tags: javascript, jquery

on opening microsoft health video page i have logs in console like this...
[image]
now i want to run a function `checkingRewardsCriteria()` from the console
[image]
but i do not know how find path of it as the js file has starting like this
[image]

for example like `this.checkingRewardsCriteria()`

i have tried like this  `this.checkingRewardsCriteria()`, `self.checkingRewardsCriteria()`

Comment: hey @anuj copy-paste the code (and logs) to the post so it's easier to read and help you out,

Comment: You can't call that function from the console because it's bundled with Webpack only code that is in an original file created by Microsoft developers can run this code.